# Trying to parse a table within table within a table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, python-3.3

I'm trying to parse this address:

[LINK](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogPriceGuide.asp?P=3005&colorID=1&viewExclude=N&v=P)

using this and alterations of this code:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url=('http://www.bricklink.com/catalogPriceGuide.asp?P=3005&colorID=1&viewExclude=N&v=P')
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
content = soup.find('table')
price=content.findAll('td')

print(price)
```

I've tried almost every combination of `table`, `find` and `findAll` all I want is for it to spit out the left most table something like

```
Times Sold: 2958
Total Qty:  130610
Min Price:  $0.0136
Avg Price:  $0.0690
Qty Avg Price:  $0.0659
Max Price:  $0.3900
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and point me in the right direction?

Comment: FYI: "*We request that you do not use any robot, spider, other automatic device, or manual process to monitor or copy our web pages or the content contained herein without our prior expressed written permission.*" - http://www.bricklink.com/help.asp?helpID=139&viewType=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's some `id`, `class`, use that. But in the given url, there's no useful `id`, `class`.

Use text text as follow:

```
>>> import re
>>> import urllib.request
>>>
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>
>>>
>>> url = 'http://www.bricklink.com/catalogPriceGuide.asp?P=3005&colorID=1&viewExclude=N&v=P'
>>> page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
>>> td = soup.find('td', text=re.compile('Times Sold'))
>>> tr_list = td.parent.parent.find_all('tr')
>>> for tr in tr_list:
...     print(' '.join(td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')))
...
Times Sold: 2958
Total Qty: 130610
Min Price: $0.01
Avg Price: $0.07
Qty Avg Price: $0.07
Max Price: $0.39
```